# Pyvista delaunay_3d settings issues for small PolyData coordinates

Tags: python, geometry, mesh, pyvista

I am trying to create script to fully automatize wind turbine blade model generation. I am using pyvista library and I am encountering some issues with **delaunay_3d** function.
To obtain hight quality .stl model it's crucial to have dense airfoil coordinates distribution and since and this results in really small dx and dy variation and values.

I don't know how to handle **delaunay_3d** function settings to properly generete 3d volume of the blade on the trailing edge of the blade. I tried to experimentally change the settings either to very low or very high, but none of this methods work. The only approach that worked, was to scale up geometry coordinates, but then i have to scale the whole model down and I would rather avoid it.

Here you can see the blade and low quality trailing edge:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHFtm.png)
I am trying to achieve this curvature:
[wanted outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMK18.png)
Here a comparison. Upper part shows normal coordinates while the lover coordinates scaled up by a value of 100. In both cases **delaunay_3d** settings were as follows:

```
te_volume = te_mesh.delaunay_3d(alpha=3, tol=0.5, offset=2.5, progress_bar=True)
```

[comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ciihl.png)

If anyone could help and explain how does the particular function settings work, as will probably know it later during the model manipulation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're saying that the same point cloud gives a different result when scaled up, this has to be due to the tolerance setting. Try `tol=1e-5` and smaller to see if it changes anything (`tol` is claimed to be in `mesh.length` units). If decreasing the tolerance doesn't do anything, I recommend [opening an issue on github](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues). Compute first what tolerance you need based on expected point distances near the edge.

Comment: Well, "has to be" is a stretch, but that's what I'd check first. It might be unrelated though, not sure now.

Comment: The tag [tag:STL] is used improperly. Please read its description carefully.

Comment: Dear Andreas, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately decreasing the tolerance even to extremely small values didn't impact the mesh quality. As a posted before. I tried to play with the function settings, setting them to wither large or small values in different combinations, but non of them worked ;( Thanks for sending the link to github forum. Take care

Comment: Without any actual specifics (and code) it's hard to guess what you could and couldn't have tried.